# ASP.NET C# Get Facebook user details

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I start to working with the Facebook graph API and I have question:
I make Facebook Authentication, so after user approve my application I got accessToken and the facebookUserID. note: The accessToken is expire after One hour(!!!).

Then, in another webpage "index.html", I want to show all the users who approved the application with their full name and profile picture taken from Facebook.

Now I don't understand..  if someone will enter the "index.html" page to see list of users who accepted the application - **5**(!!) month after their authentication, when i will make the HTTP call to get thier fullname and profile picture, the accessToken is now expire(a lot time before) so the HTTP call will not succeed.
The last option is to save the full name just in the One hour between user accept the application and before the accesstoken expiration. but if the user will change his name sometime... I don't have the updated Name!

if its important - I'm usind the javascriptSDK with asp.net project.
Please help me to understand how to solve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it is not possible to generate a long-lived token with the JS SDK directly, you will have to involve the server side, see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) for details.